# Is it possible to use a implicit function in match case?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have enum like this.

```
  object SortCountryField extends Enumeration {
    type SortCountryField = Value
    val countryName = Value("country_name")
    val countryStatus = Value("country_status")
  }
```

I'm using this `SortCountryField` enum in `match-case`.
Here I need to convert toString every time.

To make it convenient I'm trying to `implicit` converter to extract `String` from `SortCountryField.{Value}`

However, I end up having a compiler error when I use the implicit function in following match case.

```
'myString' match{
    case SortCountryField.countryName.toString => //Some operations
    case SortCountryField.countryStatus.toString => //another operation
}
```

---

Error Log:-

```
 found   : mypackage.ConstantUtils.SortCountryField.Value
[error]  required: String
[error]         case SortCountryField.countryStatus => //my-operations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using the enum in your match like:

```
SortCountryField withName <your_string> match {
    case SortCountryField.countryName => //Some operations
    case SortCountryField.countryStatus => //another operation
}
```

If your string sometimes doesn't match any field then you can easily wrap this in a `Try` like in the following code:

```
Try(SortCountryField withName <your_string>) match {
    case Success(SortCountryField.countryName) => //Some operations
    case Success(SortCountryField.countryStatus) => //another operation
    case _ => //another operation
}
```

Comment: How do we wrap nonmatching string in Try? I meant, have no idea how to write it I'm scala.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the code for using `Try`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
'myString' match{
   case x if x == SortCountryField.countryName.toString => //Some operations
   case x if x == SortCountryField.countryStatus.toString => //another operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your implicit converter looks like?
My guess is that you have converter `SortCountryField => String`, but you need `SortCountryField.Value => String` converter.

Answer (score 0):

Add below function in your enum:

```
implicit def toString(value: Value): String = value.toString
```

Use below in matching:

```
val countryStaus:String = SortCountryField.countryStatus

'myString' match {
    case `countryStatus` => //Some operations
    case _ => // Another operation
}
```